# any ways to sort a array in javascript from external json file

Tags: javascript, json, html

I am working on javascript and rickshaw.js. and I have a set of data which is been stored in a external .json file. so when i tried to call and print it. it prints the objects in alphabetical order. so is there any way to attain the arrays to display in the same sequential order as it is in the `.json` file?

Comment: That depends on the data structure. If it is an object (which it seems to be), then no, because properties don't have an order.

Comment: Could you perhaps show the JSON in question? JavaScript objects don't have an inherent ordering of properties, so if you parse the JSON to create an object you can't get the properties in the same order they were in the JSON string (that is you can't _guarantee_ to get them in that order). But arrays _do_ have an inherent ordering, so you could (re)structure your JSON to make use of that...

Comment: @nnnnn. i have even added the a small part of json file.

Comment: That's not valid JSON on its own; does the complete version have enclosing square brackets? If so then it should retain its order - that's how arrays work...